# Logging into Instapaper with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, afnetworking

If I wanted to login to Instapaper (http://www.instapaper.com/user/login) within an app where the user has put the username and password within a UITextField and login using AFNetworking, how would I accomplish this?

Is it to do with this method? http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/postPath:parameters:success:failure:

Basically I want to take the credentials, log in to Instapaper and then interact with the website that loads.

If it is the above method, do I use an NSDictionary for parameters where it's 'username'->'', and 'password'->'' or something? And is the response the HTML of the page that presents after login (what I'm looking for)?

I'm new to networking, so I'm a little confused how I'd use AFNetworking to accomplish this.

Comment: I wrote an open source instapaper api client that may be a good example. https://github.com/Keithbsmiley/KSInstapaperAPI

Comment: That API only allows saving/queuing of articles, right? I'm looking for retrieval.

Comment: Ah yes, you're correct, I didn't see mention of this in your post. Also just a note you have to have a paid Instapaper account to be able to use the full API, which I believe uses OAuth and would be slightly more in-depth to work with. http://www.instapaper.com/api/full

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AFHTTPRequestOperation` variant of `AFHTTPClient`, If you are sending username and password as parameters then add them into a NSDictionary as follows and send them as params, otherwise you can send them as formData if you want to send them in the body.

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 [parameters setObject:username.text forKey:@"username"];
 [parameters setObject:password.text forKey:@"password"];   

AFHTTPClient  *afHttpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourbaseURL"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [afHttpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/pathifAny" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
                                        {
                                        // here you can send as body if you not setting as parameters
                                        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[username.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"username"];
                                        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[password.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"password"];

                                        }];



AFHTTPRequestOperation  *afHttpReqOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
```

[Here is simple tutorial about GET/POST](http://samwize.com/2012/10/25/simple-get-post-afnetworking/)

Comment: How do I do things on success and fail?

Comment: `[afHttpReqOperation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"success: %@", operation.responseString);

} 
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);

}
 ];`

Comment: You can have a look at [AFHTTPRequestOperation](http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html) page where you can see all methods

Comment: Okay, with this and the setCompletionBlockWithSuccess: method I get a "success" occurring every time.

Comment: debug your code and see what you are sending as parameters or for login details.

Comment: The correct information, but it sends me this each time it "succeeds" as HTML: <body style="font: Normal 26px 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, sans-serif;
                  text-align:center; color:#888; margin-top:100px;">
                      Logging in...
                      <br/>
                      <br/>
                      <a href="/u" style="font-size: 11px;
                      color: #aaa;">Click here if you aren&#039;t redirected</a>
                  </body>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27044/discussion-between-doug-smith-and-nsgulliver)